# How to add plug-in to xrmtoolbox

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrmtoolbox

I have XrmToolBox 2015 and I want to add a new dll (new functionality) to my tool, but I can't find any documentation about it, how can I do that?

** I need to add DeltaAssemblyvsCrm plugin, FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install any applicable plugins to XrmToolBox from Plugins store. [Read more](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/documentation/for-users/first-steps-with-xrmtoolbox/)

> The Plugins Store is located in the menu **Tools > Plugins Store**

[image]

[DeltaAssemblyvsCrm](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Carfup.XTBPlugins.DeltaAssemblyvsCrm/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/carfup/XTBPlugins.DeltaAssemblyvsCrm/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thank you Aron! you know everything :) I now found that I don't have the tools option on my XRMTOOLBOX I'll check it